# How to Deserialize deeply nested json array in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

JSon String is given below:

```
 {   
    "properties": {
    "jci": [
                {
                    "firstName": "Henk",
                    "lastName": "de Vries",
                    "Photo": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/mendeley-photos/6a/bd/6abdab776feb7a1fd4e5b4979ea9c5bfc754fd29.png",
                    "Title": "Dr.",
                    "Position": "Head of research group",
                    "Institution": "Vrije Universiteit Amsterdam",
                    "Fields_of_interest": ["medicine", "computer science"],
                    "emailAddress": "henk.de.vries@science.com",
                    "editorship": [
                        {
                            "title": "Dr.",
                            "editorial_role": "Editor in chief",
                            "date_start": 1460116283,
                            "date_end": 1460116283,
                            "publisher": {
                                "name": "Elsevier",
                                "role": "Project manager",
                                "emailAddress": "journal@elsevier.com"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "sid": [
                {
                    "firstName": "Henk",
                    "lastName": "de Vries",
                    "Title": "Dr.",
                    "primary organisation": "Vrije Universiteit Amsterdam",
                    "emailAddress": "henk.de.vries@science.com",
                    "editorship": [
                        {
                            "title": "Dr.",
                            "editorial_role": "Editor in chief",
                            "publication_year": 2012
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I have written code to deserialization

```
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        JsonTest foo = new JsonTest();
                         foo = (JsonTest)ser.Deserialize<JsonTest>(JSONString);

public class JsonTest
    {
        public properties properties { get; set; }
    }
    public class properties
    {

        public List<jci> jci { get; set; }
        public List<sid>sid { get; set; }
    }

public class jci
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Institution { get; set; }
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<string> Fields_of_interest { get; set; }
        public List<editorship> editorship { get; set; }

    }
    public class editorship
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string editorial_role { get; set; }
        public string date_start { get; set; }
        public string date_end { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> publisher { get; set; }
    }
```

in this code there are 2 arrays of object called "editorship".. I have created "editorship" class for "jci".. how to access the values of editorship array of sid...?

Comment: have you tried create a class using http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 2):

Using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/#) i generated these classes based on your JSON

```
public class Publisher
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Editorship
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string editorial_role { get; set; }
    public int date_start { get; set; }
    public int date_end { get; set; }
    public Publisher publisher { get; set; }
}

public class Jci
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Institution { get; set; }
    public List<string> Fields_of_interest { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Editorship> editorship { get; set; }
}

public class Editorship2
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string editorial_role { get; set; }
    public int publication_year { get; set; }
}

public class Sid
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string primary_organisation { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Editorship2> editorship { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public List<Jci> jci { get; set; }
    public List<Sid> sid { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}
```

You can then access your editorial values like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var collection = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonString);

foreach (var j in collection.properties.sid)
{
  Console.Write(j.editorship);
}
```

On a side note, you should consider using names that are more readable then *jci* and *sid*

Comment: Thanks for your answer